# How to redirect in a Loopback 4 authentication strategy?

Tags: node.js, authentication, loopbackjs

In v3, the [Passport middleware](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js) `authenticate` function was in charge of augmenting the instance of Strategy with functions `success`, `fail`, `redirect`, `pass`, `error` and `authenticate`.

In v4, where middlewares are no longer used, there is the [StrategyAdapter](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/packages/authentication/src/strategy-adapter.ts)  `authenticate` function that adds all the functions, except `redirect` and `pass`.

How can I implement an OpenID Connect based authentication without the `redirect` function?

Answer (score 2):

*Hello from the LoopBack team :)*

The authentication component was meant as a reference implementation showing users how to write their own authentication layer and as such it was tested only for a limited number of scenarios.

I think you have just discovered a limitation of the current implementation. Could you please open a [new GitHub issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/new) where we can discuss the specifics and find a solution?